# Sorting and Reordering columns using Excel Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a set of excel columns as follows (with n number of rows and columns) [image]

I want it to be Sorted and reordered using the group, but I need it to be done using the formula, and not the simple sorting option in excel. The results expected are as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? Sorting the data by the values in the "group" column or changing the order of the columns from "name/group/value" to "group/name/value"?? Please **edit your question** to provide the clarification, then post a comment to alert people who are following the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not clear on what you are asking. What does "I need it to be done using the formula, and not the simple sorting option" mean?

Comment: Formulas can NOT to perform the action you need. The cell may contain either formula or value, not both. SP. *I need it to be done using the formula, and not the simple sorting option in excel.* Why? this is a learning task?

Comment: @teylyn: I want it to be sorted by the group the reordered as group/name/value. The data will dynamically change in a specific sheet in excel. So the results of this question will be in a different sheet and using formula, it should dynamically sort and group the data and display. That is why a simple sorting using the inbuilt excel option will not be effective. Hope this clarifies the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods, **1**st is non programming (using Excel Formula) and **2**nd is VBA macro (programming method).*

## Caveat:

*The prime reason behind suggesting VBA macro is, since the **1**st method (using Excel formula) is multi folded & a kind of a tedious method.*

---

**Method 1:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- For Helper data,

Formula in Cell `F55:`

```
=COUNTIF(B$55:B$60,"<="&B55)
```

Formula in Cell `G55:`

```
=SMALL($F$55:$F$60,ROW(A1))
```

*Fill both formula down.*

- **S**ort by group, formula in Cell `A63:`, fill it down.

  ```
   =INDEX(B$55:B$60,MATCH(G55,F$55:F60),0)
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula,

  In Cell `B63:`

  ```
   {=INDEX($A$55:$A$60, MATCH(0, IF($A63=$B$55:$B$60, COUNTIF($B$62:$B62, $A$55:$A$60), ""), 0)}
  ```

**N.B.** Finish with **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter & fill down.

In Cell `C63:`

```
  {=INDEX(C$55:C$60, MATCH(0, IF($A63=$B$55:$B$60, COUNTIF(C$62:C62, C$55:C$60), ""), 0))}
```

**N.B.** Finish with **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter & fill **D**own then **R**ight.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

- For neatness you may hide **H**elper Data.

---

**Method 2:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select Range `A71:D77` and in Name Box (top left corner) write name `Mydata`.
- From **D**eveloper TAB hit **D**esign then **I**nsert.
- Now, from **A**ctiveX Controls select **C**ommand Button then draw it on Sheet.
- **D**ouble Click the **C**ommand Button to open VB editor.
- Copy & Paste this code between

**P**rivate Sub CommadButton1_Click()

*Copy Code here*

**E**nd Sub

```
    Range("MyData").Sort Key1:=Range("MyData").Cells(2, 2), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

- **S**ave & return to the Sheet.
- Turn Off **D**esign Mode then **D**ouble Click the Command Button.
- You get data in following order:

[image]

**N.B.** Source data range `A71:D77` & **R**ange Name `Mydata` are editable.